# Create column to constantly update with rownum in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, rownum

I have a table in SQL Server database. It has a column `testrownum`. I want to update the `testrownum` column to be rownum whenever row is created in the table automatically.

Is there any setting that I can turn on to achieve this?

Comment: you mean something like a trigger?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "rownum" in a SQL Server table.... the data in a table is an **unordered bag** of data - there is no implied ordering and therefore no "numbering" of rows

Comment: Can you explain to us *why* you need that row number?

Comment: Why don't you create an identity column.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid He could indeed and then use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY row_id)` (`row_id` being the `IDENTITY` column) to get contiguous row numbers.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for the advises.

Comment: Basically I am working with a table that has been created by a vendor and they have their logic in inserting records and primary keys. So to get the right identity column I thought it would be ideal to get the rownumber and use it in my own application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is best to get a row number at the time you `SELECT` your data, by using the [`ROW_NUMBER()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms186734.aspx).

As others have pointed out (comments section) the data in a table is essentially unordered. You can however assign a row number for a certain ordering when you select data as follows (suppose a table that only has one column being `name`):

```
SELECT
  name,
  rownr=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)
FROM
  name_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create trigger function.

Trigger is a function which is called every time data is insert, update or delete from table (you can specify when you want your function to be called when creating trigger). So you can add two triggers, one for insert and one for delete and just increment/decrement value you want.